# how do I find a random number within a range while excluding numbers

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm currently assigning records to servers using a modulus of the primary key which is resulting to an even distribution. Sometimes I need to take one of the servers down and I don't want the records to build up while it's offline.

Current SQL

```
UPDATE table
SET server_id = ((primary_key % 10000) + 1)
WHERE server_id IS NULL;
```

I am trying to avoid a second SQL statement so if you have another idea, I'd love to hear it.

Comment: This would be easier if you had a table of servers that are up.  Do you have such a table (or query)?

Comment: @jbrahy I'm not sure what you mean when you write 'build up'. Are you using insert statements somewhere?

Comment: @GordonLinoff I do have a table of servers that I wasn't using in this query but I could use it and change a status_id when a server is going down.

Comment: @Drew by "build up" have a record routing application that does all the inserts. This is a different application than this one that assigns the records to servers for processing. So building up means that they would be assigning new records to an offline server and without the server processing those records it would be building up a queue of records to process when it comes back online.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want something like the following:

```
update table t join
       (select s.*, @rn := @rn + 1 as FakeServerNumber, NumServers
        from servers s cross join
             (select count(*) as NumServers, @rn := -1
              from servers
              where isup = 'isup'
             ) const
        where s.isup = 'isup'
       ) s 
       on t.primary_key % s.NumServer = s.rn
    set t.server_id = s.server_id
    where t.server_id is null;
```

This adds a sequential number to all the "up" servers.  It uses this for the `join` back the modulus expression on the primary key.  You can then insert the actual server information into your table.